# WKWebView App Rejected By Apple Due To Crash

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, wkwebview

I have uploaded my WKWebView app that just loads website data to the app and it is running fine on my side but when I uploaded it to AppStore, apple rejected it saying "We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue". App minimum deployment target is 11.1 and the Xcode version is 11.3.1. any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

[Crash Report Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgq3j.png)

Here is my entire code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var refreshView: UIStackView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    initializeView()
    
}


private func initializeView(){
       
   webView.navigationDelegate = self
   
   guard let url = URL(string: "https://appybag.com") else {
       return
   }
   
   let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
   
   webView.load(urlRequest)
   
   refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
   refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(reloadWebView), for: .valueChanged)
   webView.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
       
}
   
@objc private func reloadWebView(){
    
   refreshView.isHidden = true
    
   if let _ = webView.url {
       webView.reload()
   } else {
       guard let url = URL(string: "https://appybag.com") else {
           return
       }
       webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
   }
    
   refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    ProgressHUD.show()
    print("loading")
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    ProgressHUD.dismiss()
    print("loaded")
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    refreshView.isHidden = false
    ProgressHUD.dismiss()
    print("failed to load")
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    ProgressHUD.dismiss()
    refreshView.isHidden = false
}
```

}

And here are crash reports link:

https://iosapps-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Purple123/v4/04/67/a2/0467a228-b74d-c9cc-7eb9-bebd13fac665/attachment-595762434851874863crashlog-AC94124F-204D-434E-8A1D-73A9355358FE.txt?accessKey=1591425677_7212368649932022101_ovHEGrHgVDTVg4wyC3tIiJOCMqwRHkjjpeICOnRTwTkmey%2FQafeIpk2ojIJH0MONv258wI4s0lb%2ByhLQsQ3%2FSsoV5SXMsmiYmqZo6ZyW3e96DqnfgTo8UnQdZJpZA7y3uWUnmFLgeB7M1SuWDsE3QyYTR1jLwSe1%2FZHoD2S1NGCz3BnV2vAlyYDHSR08wl3dgVD5ok%2FvoMAaKgkKSlz4ER7%2FO%2BnStmF82IeEi1CklxV1KjON2w%2Fmvv6iMIMV%2F%2BGT

https://iosapps-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Purple113/v4/95/d2/90/95d2909c-77d2-6593-3f26-6509c40c1f42/attachment-1735289411846494652crashlog-66DECCAE-BDA0-45B1-B3DA-94EDF504BF70.txt?accessKey=1591425677_7573732762115220118_SdP0MyNEDi%2BIm3fdnXeyEvl8RghEpk9WNyjyO5NZABlXcSmq0E4x%2BxZSsMaX7JJrN2OZz8VioTcOLVkeYa6MGnLefuNCcziBb%2FtwI6nOdK4niJ%2Bv4r4k0HmE89QfZYP4tXYihYX%2FCszG2WHA5DGQvAcicnGG8%2FgbU4elJGzx%2Ft4JmFNF%2B74xXO52EfSSZDh2pZ8Q9o1yeqKYdtXe6h3AvuodEeHWEgaZmk0N%2Bv7j6ALd3lJmvaCAlcasp0XjzNke

Comment: Please show us the apple rejection message and you can show the screenshots

Comment: I have attached the report screenshot, kindly take a look at this

Comment: is your app crashing in xcode?

Comment: 1) you need to symbolicate the crash log to see what the error is. 2) you might have trouble getting this into the app store regardless of crashing, as apps that merely wrap a website, are discouraged

Comment: @ZainAnjum no it's not crashing in XCode

Comment: Even if they don't reject it for simply being a web site (which they probably will), they will probably reject it for the google play link that appears at the bottom if the page.